# Does Leo Valdez ever come back in Percy Jackson?

Tags: percy-jackson

Once Leo Valdez reaches Ogygia for the second time, does he ever come back to visit with the other characters, or appear at Camp Half Blood?

Neither Percy nor Annabeth mention anything about him in *Staff of Serapis* or *Son of Sobek*.

Comment: Almost certainly. Although he never re-appears he plans to return, and as soon as he and Calypso are safe and Festus is repaired he will return. Also Nico and Hazel are unsure whether he is truly dead and will probably be on the lookout for anything Leo related such as Leo starting a garage.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes.

Originally announced by Rick Riordan at his event for the release of *Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard*, all of the major characters from *Percy Jackson and the Olympians* and *The Heroes of Olympus* will be revisited - including Leo.

And, in *The Trials of Apollo*, he does come back - and people set up a ticket line for people to punch him.

> Nico commandeered a dispenser from the snack bar and carried it around, yelling, “The line starts to the left! Orderly queue, guys!”
>   “Is this really necessary?” Leo asked.
>   “Yes,” said Miranda Gardiner, who had drawn the first number. She punched Leo in the arm. “Ow,” said Leo.
>   “You’re a jerk, and we all hate you,” said Miranda. Then she hugged him and kissed his cheek. “If you ever disappear like that again, we’ll line up to *kill* you.”
>   “Okay, okay!”
>   <sub>*The Trials of Apollo*, book 1: *The Hidden Oracle*, chapter 39: "Want to hit Leo? / That is understandable / Hunk Muffin earned it"</sub>

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Leo has never appeared outside of the *Heroes of Olympus* series. At the end of the last book in that series, *Blood of Olympus*, he heads off to Ogygia with Calypso to live happily ever after, and isn't mentioned after that.

As far as I know, *Son of Sobek* and *Staff of Serapis* actually take place before *Blood of Olympus*, so they wouldn't be any help here. However, there's a sequel to *Staff of Serapis*, **Crown of Ptolemy**, that does take place after the end of the *Heroes* series, and I don't remember Leo being mentioned in that one either.

(Of course, Riordan's still writing these crossover books, so we might hear more about him in the future, but so far, I think he's flown off into the sunset.)

Answer (score 3):

He does come back in the series of "Trials of Apollo" and was beaten up by the campers.

Yeah he returned - with Calypso.

He meets Percy first but I don't know if he met Jason and the others yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

> "Leo had returned."
>   <sub>The Hidden Oracle, End of Chapter 38.</sub>

Literally the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Leo comes back in the Trials of Apollo series with Calypso. All the campers at Camp Half-Blood stand in line to punch him and tell him never to disappear like that again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems to be the same answer as the highest-voted existing answer, which makes posting it a bit redundant.  Is there anything you can add to make this answer better or more complete?  Please read [answer].

Answer (score -2):

He comes back with Riordan's new book trials of apollo, it came out roughly a year ago and the next book in that series comes out in a week or so from posting this comment.

Comment: Can you provide evidence? A snippet of text, perhaps?